# Identifying DC electrical power connector

Tags: power, dc, connector, identification

I have here a PowerFilm 10 Watt F15-600 Solar Panel, and attached to the panel is this connector:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The male end attached to the panel has a little green rubber gasket on it and the female end goes to a 12V female "port" into which you can put a 12V male cigarette adapter.

Notice how there is a gap in the right-side of the male plug and how there is a corresponding slot in the female one so that the polarity won't be reversed. Also, the clip won't attach if it was reversed.

I am just wondering if there's a place I could get more of these female ends so I can make more water-resistant attachments to the solar panel. The socket is a pretty good design, but I wonder if it is a proprietary design.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're out of luck. If you have access to a 3D printer you may be able to model and print a copy.

Comment: That looks like some of the connectors you see on modern cars.

Comment: That would be a fun project but there seems to be a low return on investment. The other side of the female end has a folding snappy sleeve thing and also has rubber bits where the cables go in. I can't actually figure out how to take it apart properly.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Can you recall where you found some of those? Just the stuff found on various electrical wiring on various vehicles, I presume. "proprietary design" sounds like a good bet, and I'd have to get quite lucky to find suitable replacement parts, I guess.

Comment: Looks like @NickAlexeev found them in his answer. I think I saw them somewhere like [r/justrolledintotheshop](http://www.reddit.com/r/Justrolledintotheshop/). Not a particularly linkable resource.

Comment: Awesome! ... For reference purposes my first comment (originally a comment on a now-removed answer) was in response to a suggestion to perhaps 3D-print the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a connector from [Weather Pack](http://delphi.com/manufacturers/cv/connection-systems/weather-pack-connectors/) family.

[image]

These connectors are often used in American cars and motorcycles.  So, they are fairly common in the US.  For instance, an auto parts store near my house carries them.

Comment: The only way to adequately express my gratitude at this point is with a healthy smattering of expletives. It is quite easy to find these connectors on e.g. eBay now that we know what to search for.

Comment: @StevenLu  Folks here on EE.SE were able to identify a lot more obscure connectors than yours.  When it comes to connectorology, EE.SE has got some brain trust.

Comment: Yup! I knew i picked the right place to ask the question